# NetBeans 11.3 waiting for connection to Xdebug

Tags: php, netbeans, xdebug

I am using Windows 10, NetBeans 11.3, PHP7.4.9, Apache/2.4.46 (Win64), XAMPP v3.2.4 and MySQL.

My php.ini file has the following settings:

```ini
output_buffering=off

[XDebug]

zend_extension = "c:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.9.7-7.4-vc15-x86_64.dll"
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.profiler_append = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "c:\xampp\tmp"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = "localhost:81"
xdebug.remote_log = "c:\xampp\tmp\xdebug.txt"
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "c:\xampp\tmp"
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time = 36000
```

NetBeans configuration:

```
Debugger port: 9000
Session ID: netbeans-xdebug
Stop at first line: Checked
All other options are unchecked
```

When I click on debugging icon (<kbd>Ctrl + F5</kbd>) it gets stuck on "waiting for connection (netbeans-xdebug)" while shows the page completely without stopping at the break points.

Answer (score 1):

`xdebug.remote_host = "localhost:81"` is certainly not correct. The `remote_host` should have the value of the IP address or hostname where your IDE runs. This is likely just `localhost`.

You should also upgrade to Xdebug 3.1, which has much better logging functionality for troubleshooting connection errors through it's [`xdebug_info()`](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_functions#xdebug_info) function, and [`xdebug.log`](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#log) and [`xdebug.log_level`](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_functions#xdebug_info) settings.

Please do refer to the upgrade guide though, as some setting names have changed. You would likely only need:

```
zend_extension = "c:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-3.1.3-7.4-vc15-x86_64.dll"
xdebug.mode=develop,debug       # replacement for xdebug.remote_enable
xdebug.start_with_request=1     # replacement for xdebug.remote_autostart
xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
xdebug.client_port = 9000       # replacement for xdebug.remote_port
                                # I would recommend to use the default 9003,
                                # but you need to update Netbeans config to
                                # say the same too.
```